# Assert Exception message not showing

Tags: java, assertion

Hi I'm currently working on an assignment where I have to check if the Resident Password matches with the Door password or not, I have to give the user three tries and after that use assert to show to tell the user to try again. this is my code but the assert is not showing any message.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // write your code here
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String P, pas;
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter Resident Password: ");
        pas = s.next();
        System.out.println("Enter Door Password: ");
        P = s.next();
        Resident r = new Resident("XYZ", pas);
        Door d = new Door(P);
        Dorm D = new Dorm();
        D.Check();
        if (Resident.getPassword().equals(Door.getPassword())) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    assert i>2 : "Serious Error – Program has been terminated Try again later";
}
```

what should I do to get the message using assert.

Comment: Maybe I didn't get the question right, are you trying to display error message to the console? Like using: `System.err.println("Serious Error – Program has been terminated Try again later")` after checking if the retry is exceeded?

Comment: Yes thats what I'm trying to do

Comment: I would suggest, not use `assert` and use `System.err.println` which is more elegant to display on the command line.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!  If an answer helps you, you should up-vote it (click on the upwards facing triangle by the question).  If there are any answers that help you solve the problem, you should pick one of them and click on the check-mark by it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable

> By default, assertions are disabled at runtime. Two command-line switches allow you to selectively enable or disable assertions. To enable assertions at various granularities, use the `-enableassertions`, or `-ea`, switch

Comment: i've already enabled it but it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

The way `assert` works with sending an error message is via using ensuring the condition fails in the case you want. For example:

`assert <condition> : <message-if-condition-is-false>;`

So if you change your assert to use:

```
assert i<=2 : "Serious Error – Program has been terminated Try again later";
```

You throw `if i is still <=2`. If the condition fails, then the message gets thrown as AssertionError.

So with the above, if I execute it as:

```
javac Example.java
java -ea Example
```

and give the desired wrong inputs, you would get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Serious Error, Program has been terminated Try again later
```

Anyhow, you could choose to use `System.err` and output the error message:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Write your code here
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String P, pas;
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter Resident Password: ");
        pas = s.next();

        System.out.println("Enter Door Password: ");
        P = s.next();

        Resident r = new Resident("XYZ", pas);
        Door d = new Door(P);
        Dorm D = new Dorm();
        D.Check();

        if (Resident.getPassword().equals(Door.getPassword())) {
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    // This need not be verified with if (i>2) because the System.exit(0); will exit if the condition satisfies
    System.err.println("Serious Error – Program has been terminated Try again later");
}
```

Comment: Happy that it helped. @DuaKhan do mark the answer if it's the appropriate one.